# Which adapter is more suitable for a pressure transducer?

Tags: sensor, adapter

For my student project, I'm going to be using a 4-20 mA and +/- 10 V output pressure transducers and the output of these sensors will be going into a DAQ system that we purchased from DEWESOFT. Along with the DAQ system, we will be purchasing additional adapters that were suggested by the company and I am confused regarding which one to pick.

There is a voltage adapter called DSI-V-200 that takes up to +/- 200 V excitation. It's official description on the website is :
"DSI-V-200 adapter will enable any DSUB9 analog input to accept ±200V voltage range, differential input via BNC connector. Bandwidth and ranges are defined by the connected amplifier."

The other adapter is a current adapter which I believe might be more suitable called the DSI- 20 mA, which is used for direct current measurement. The official description is: "DSI-20mA - 20mA current input adapter with internal shunt 50 Ohm, 0.05% accuracy for sensors with 4 to 20 mA output."

My question is whether voltage or current adapters are more suitable for a 4-20 mA industrial pressure sensor? Can anyone explain whether reading voltage or current measurements from an industrial pressure sensor is more appropriate?

Here is the link to the pressure transducer spec sheet: http://www.futek.com/files/pdf/Product%20Drawings/pmp410.pdf

Comment: They aren't power supply adapters, I believe they are adaptors for sensor outputs. This is the link to their website for the adaptors so you could have a better idea: https://dewesoft.com/products/accessories/dsi-adapters

Comment: Call your Dewetron rep. For the price you pay for Dewetron equipment they'll just tell you what you need. Off the top of my head, I would think the voltage adapter would be able to be used in more situtations due to flexibility You should be able to rig it up to measure 4-20mA signals using a resistor. But it probably won't be as optimal (compact, accurate, low noise, etc) as using the current adapter.

Comment: Your question is also unclear because your very first sentence implies you are using a two different pressure transducers: a 4-20mA output and a voltage output. But then afterwards you talk as if there was only one 4-20mA transducer. Either that, or you are thinking that a 4-20mA adapter might somehow work with your voltage output transducer (which it won't, obviously).

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks for the help! I'll contact the rep.

Comment: The transducer has a voltage output of 4-20 mA and a voltage output of +/- 10 V according to its specs

Comment: I thought that the voltage output that pressure transducers correspond to pressure that it is reading and therefore a voltage adapter would make sense. I think I might be wrong though.

Comment: Something isn't quite right with your understanding off the pressure transducer. Which one is it?

Comment: This is a link to the spec sheet of the transducer, at the bottom where it says rated outputs it's written 4-20 mA and 0- 10 VDC: http://www.futek.com/files/pdf/Product%20Drawings/pmp410.pdf

Comment: That transducer comes in two versions. a 4-20mA output version and a 0-10VDC version. You need to decide which you want to use. Until then I'll vote to close this question since that makes your original question moot.